# multiple id sequences in a mysql table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, backbone.js

I have a accounting application that has a feature called company profiles which in turn has a field called "InvoicePrefix". So if i have a company with invoice prefix as MY, all invoices should be generated as MY/2013-2014/001 and so on...
Similarly if i have invoicePrefix as ME, the invoices should start from ME/2013-2014/001 and so on.

Now i have a common invoices table in mysql for all the companies as i don't know the number of companies in prior.

What i need is the invoice sequence to start from 1 for each invoicePrefix. Currently i am generating invoice numbers (that appears at last -MY/2013-2014/**001**). This has a problem that the sequence breaks for each company.

So how can i accomplish this with some smart mysql query statements?

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a seed table which records current pointer for each of your companies like

```
Company | Year      | Seed
MY      | 2013-2014 |  1
ME      | 2013-2014 |  20
ME      | 2012-2013 |  1120
```

Create a proc for inserting records in your table first check whether company records is there in table for that particular year, if not insert that record and start seed counter with `1` else get the latest seed value and update the counter and after getting the value insert the record accordingly in your table.

Comment: i am having autoincrement column id which provides the new values to invoice numbers...

Comment: That id will be common for all the companies? For generating a separate id for your table you can follow this approach. Do you have any problem in understanding it ?